# How to get a function to execute

Tags: python

I have a function and I want it to execute. Does anyone know how to do this?

```
def a():

    a = 'print'
    print a
```

Comment: What Python tutorial are you following?  I'd like to know which book left you with this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this you just use.

```
a()
```

If you want this for use inside the current file use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': a()
```

And if you want to pass the variable a on for use in other functions use:

```
if __name__ == '__main__': b = a()
```

The 'b' being the variable and 'a' being the function you have defined.

So the whole function could look like this:

```
def a():

    b = 'print'
    print b

if __name__ == '__main__': b = a()
```

Comment: The `if __name__ == '__main__':` is very confusing.  Why do you write that so many times?

Comment: @ S.Lott - I have taken note of your advice and don't have it written everywhere now. It is entered once at the bottom of the file.

Comment: After that the function `a` is shadowed by the variable `a`. Not good.

Comment: @lutz, I was keeping the variable names and function names the same as the question asked. Edited now

Answer (score 14):

The name of your function is `a`. It takes no arguments. So call it using `a()`:

```
>>> def a():
...     a = 'print'
...     print a
... 
>>> a()
print
```

Note that you *shadow* the definition of `a` as a function within `a` itself, by defining a local variable with that same name. You may want to avoid that, as it may confuse you or other readers of your code. Also, it makes it impossible to apply [recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_%28computer_science%29).

Anyway, in general, if `f` is some function object then you can call it by putting parentheses behind it, possibly containing some arguments. Example:

```
>>> def twice(text):
...     print text
...     print text
... 
>>> twice('the text I want to print twice')
the text I want to print twice
the text I want to print twice
```

Answer (score 1):

just write a() !

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but a simple function call goes as in

```
a()
```

of course, after the definition, so it would be

```
def a():

    a = 'print'
    print a

a()
```